# Error while 'composer require jenssegers/mongodb' adding MongoDB to new Laravel 7 Project

Tags: laravel, mongodb, laravel-7, jenssegers-mongodb, moloquent

After fresh installation of laravel 7 project,

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\blog>composer require jenssegers/mongodb --ignore-platform-reqs
```

But this is giving an error.

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
  Problem 1
    - jenssegers/mongodb[v3.8.0, ..., v3.8.2] require illuminate/support ^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - Root composer.json requires jenssegers/mongodb ^3.8 -> satisfiable by jenssegers/mongodb[v3.8.0, v3.8.1, v3.8.2].
```

Also unintalled old composer and installed latest version of it. But still the same issue

Comment: Check your PHP version.

Comment: Version is PHP 7.4.11  @Phemieny007

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got the issue: Need to check the laravel version compatibility with jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB. You can check it here:

https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#laravel-version-compatibility

```
Laravel version Compatibility
Laravel Package
4.2.x   2.0.x
5.0.x   2.1.x
5.1.x   2.2.x or 3.0.x
5.2.x   2.3.x or 3.0.x
5.3.x   3.1.x or 3.2.x
5.4.x   3.2.x
5.5.x   3.3.x
5.6.x   3.4.x
5.7.x   3.4.x
5.8.x   3.5.x
6.x 3.6.x
7.x 3.7.x
8.x 3.8.x
```

And in cmd i Did like this:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\blog> composer require jenssegers/mongodb 3.7
```

Hope this helps anyone with the same issue

Answer (score 5):

For Laravel 8

```
composer require jenssegers/mongodb:^3.8 --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Answer (score 2):

In Laravel 8 it worked like this:

composer require jenssegers/mongodb 3.8.x

the ".x" is important, otherwise it marks the same error in MacOs.